# REST web service calls from android device

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, network-programming

I made an android application which connects to a local web service on my desktop computer, in a network with a router.

In AVD, I managed to make calls to the web service, but I have problems when I deploy the application on my android device (connection timeout). The phone was connected to the same network, but the call does not work.

Is there a simple way to make calls to the web service from the device? What are the ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure that the url you are trying to reach is reachable. For example your computer may be behind a firewall which is not allowed to be accessed from outside the network. You can connect your phone to wireless access point on the same network as your computer.

or you can place the web service on a server that is web accessible.

Comment: i stopped the firewall from windows, but i didn't notice the antivirus firewall.